# Issue trying to set up TTS service of IBM Watson using libcurl

Tags: c++, libcurl, ibm-watson

I am trying to implement TTS service of IBM Watson using libcurl. I am sending the text "Hello World" and the voice to be synthesized will be "D:\log\Output.aac"

Setting up the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS and CURLOPT_FILE is a bit of an issue for me as I am new to libcurl. How do I correctly set these fields?  IBM Cloud service also reported error authenticating to my Watson service due use of deprecated of legacy credentials. I am lost, please help.

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

void Curl_Perform_TTS() {   
    CURL* curl;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "<url>/v1/synthesize?text=Hello%20world");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "Text to Speech-ej"); //not sure, I use service name here
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "<API key>");
        //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); //Don't work
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L); 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L); 

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, "{\"Content-Type\":\"audio/flac\", \"Transfer-Encoding: chunked\"}");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"path\":\"D:\\log\"}"); 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FILE, "{\"Output.mp3\"}");

        CURLcode result = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if (result != CURLE_OK)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(result));
        }
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Curl_Perform_TTS();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem, I think, is that you are not forming the header properly.

Looking into [libcurl documentation](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER.html) you can notice that for adding an HTTP Header

```c
CURLcode curl_easy_setopt(CURL *handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, struct curl_slist *headers);
```

You must create first a `struct curl_slist`, and pass it as the argument for `curl_easy_setopt`. For example:

```c
struct curl_slist *headerslist = NULL;

// .....
//and later when you need to add a header, do it in this way

headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerslist, "Content-Type: audio/flac");

//When you are done, clean the memory used by the linked list
//This should be done after performing the request of course
curl_slist_free_all(headerslist);
```

This could be one of your issues, the other one is related to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. Which have this interface to deal with it:

```
CURLcode curl_easy_setopt(CURL *handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, char *postdata);
```

The documentation for this one is [here](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html). An example could be as simple as this

```c
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "name=daniel&project=curl");
```

I think in general, this examples from the official documentation should help you to for the request correctly:

- [custom header](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/httpcustomheader.html)
- [http post](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/http-post.html)
- [simple post](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/simplepost.html)

And the list goes on. In case you need more examples, you could read all of them in [here also](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/example.html)

Comment: Good observation +1. I will go through these links, make take sometime but I will come back to this thread.

Comment: With the example you're gonna be able to form the pieces, and make your particular request.